# vue-test-utils: How to test logic within mounted() lifecycle hook (with vuex)?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to write a unit test for the logic within Vue's `mounted()` lifecycle hook, but not having much luck. The problem seems to be that `mounted()` never gets called when the component is mounted using vue-test-utils `mount`. Here's the Vue component I'm trying to test:

```html
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>   
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('logout')
  }
}
</script>
```

And the test itself:

```js
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  let store
  let actions

  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
      logout: jest.fn().mockName('logout')
    }
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {},
      actions
    })
  })

  it('calls store "logout" action', () => {
    mount(MyComponent, { localVue, store })
    expect(actions.logout).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

However, this fails with `expect(logout).toHaveBeenCalled()` asserting false.

If I call the mocked store action directly with `actions.logout()` the test passes, and I have other tests which also call store actions on things like a button press, and those pass as well, so the problem definitely appears to be with the mounted() lifecycle hook.

Any thoughts?

(vue `2.5.4` and vue-test-utils `1.0.0-beta-.15`)

Comment: Just tested your code with the specified versions and it works.

Comment: Try to use `1.0.0-beta.16`, it's released today

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure how it's any different, but I abstracted the store mock to another file and everything seems to work now.

`mocks.js`

```js
export const storeMock = Object.freeze({
  state: {},
  actions: {
    logout: jest.fn().mockName('logout')
  },
})
```

`test.spec.js`

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { storeMock } from './mocks.js' 
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  let options

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
    const store = new Vuex.Store(storeMock)
    options = { store, localVue }
  })

  it('calls store "logout" action', () => {
    shallowMount(MyComponent, options)
    expect(storeMock.actions.logout).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Without abstracting the store mock to another file, and slightly different approach without `beforeEach` (ruined my tests for some reason).

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent.vue";

describe("MyComponent", () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(Vuex);

  const actions = {
    logout: jest.fn()
  };
  const store = new Vuex.Store({ actions });

  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
    localVue,
    store
  });

  it('calls store "logout" action', () => {
    expect(actions.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```